# How can I set state in a function that is in a utility file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I had a function in a react class that I was using to pull data.

It was working great, but I then found out I needed to use the same function in a few other places.

So I decided to put the function in it's own file so I could re-use it.

So here it is:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const  getGalaxyName = async (id) => {
    try {
        const { data: response } = await axios.get(`/api/scienceClass/galaxy/${id}`)
        this.setState({ galaxyName: response.name });
    }

    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

And then in a component, I use it like this:

```
import { getGalaxyName } from './ScienceClassUtils';

    render() {

        getGalaxyName(slide.z_GalaxyId);
```

But now I am getting this error:

> ScienceClassUtils.js:35 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of
> undefined

I am guessing it's because I'm trying to still set the state in the function like I did when it was originally inside the react class.

So how can I still use it now that it's separated out in another file, but still have `this.setState({ galaxyName: response.name });` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are we to assume your second code block is invalid due to a copy/paste issue or just bad code?

Comment: Even if that had worked, you're not supposed to change state inside the render function.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss sorry, it was a really long file so I just included the part where I use the exported function.  I will copy in the whole file

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, originally the function was in the same file, but outside render.  But I ended up needing the same function in some other part of my code.  So I decided to move it to a separate file so I could reuse it when needed.  However I ended up creating a new problem with `setState` now... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way from here to there might be to have it return the promise instead of calling setState directly:

```js
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/scienceClass/galaxy/${id}`)
return data.name;
```

Then your component or anyone else could do whatever they need to do with it:

```js
getGalaxyName(id).then(galaxyName => this.setState({ galaxyName });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible approaches:

1. Create a helper method for setting the galaxyName and then pass it to axios utility, and it will call it and pass the response.name to it.
2. Return the response from axios utility and use *Promise* methods `.then, .catch, .finally`, to handle the *success, fail, finished* cases as needed. Note that, the data you return from the axios utility will be passed to these methods as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is you can't set the state outside a React component. Make your utility function return the data you need and set the state from within your react component.

Refactor your util function to look like this

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const  getGalaxyName = async (id) => {
    try {
        const { data: response } = await axios.get(`/api/scienceClass/galaxy/${id}`)
        return { galaxyName: response.name }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

From within your component call the method in a `componentDidMount`. lifecycle hook like this

```js
class SampleComponent extends React.component {
  
  // Add this lifecycle hook
  componentDidMount() {
    getGalaxyName(slide.z_GalaxyId).then((data) => {
      this.setState(data)
    });
  }


  render() {
    // use state data as needed here
  }

}
```